# Destruir Tedits em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi

Possuo uma aplicação que cria TEdits de 1 a 15
Gostaria que eles desaparecem, mas quando a pessoa clicar no botao de criar eles voltasem..

eles foram criados da seguinte maneira:

```
ArrayEdit[x] := TEdit.Create(Self);
ArrayEdit[x].Parent:= Self;
ArrayEdit[x].Left := 100 + x * 50;
ArrayEdit[x].Top := 124;
ArrayEdit[x].Width := 41;
ArrayEdit[x].Height :=24;
ArrayEdit[x].Name := 'edit'+ inttostr(x+20);
```

E estou destruindo eles da seguinte maneira:

```
 for i := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      If (Components[i] is tedit) then
        Tedit(Components[i]).Destroy;
    end;
```

O problema é o seguinte, ele da um erro de Acess Violation e também seeu destruir os edits terei que fechar a aplicação para usá-los novamente, alguma ideia?

Comment: Fiz aqui usando o seu código e está tudo ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas observações:

- Não execute *Destroy* diretamente, prefira usar o *Free*, que executa o
  *Destroy* apenas depois de checar se o componente realmente está alocado.
- O que você chama de "desaparecer" é realmente destruir o componente?
  Não bastaria torná-los invisíveis?

Para torná-los invisíveis bastaria fazer:

```
for i := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  If (Components[i] is tedit) then
    Tedit(Components[i]).Visible:= false;
end;
```

E para torná-los visíveis novamente, seria só fazer

```
for i := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  If (Components[i] is tedit) then
    Tedit(Components[i]).Visible:= true;
end;
```

Comment: Ou remover/adicionar o parent

Answer (score 1):

Com esse código aqui (que usa o código que você passou), está tudo ok.

```pascal
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure criarEdits;
  public

  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
    for i := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
        If (Components[i] is tedit) then
            Tedit(Components[i]).Destroy;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm2.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    criarEdits;
end;

procedure TForm2.criarEdits;
var
  i : Integer;
  arrayEdit : array[1..15] of TEdit;
begin
  for i := 1 to 15 do
  begin
    ArrayEdit[i] := TEdit.Create(Self);
    ArrayEdit[i].Parent:= Self;
    ArrayEdit[i].Left := 100 + i * 50;
    ArrayEdit[i].Top := 124;
    ArrayEdit[i].Width := 41;
    ArrayEdit[i].Height :=24;
    ArrayEdit[i].Name := 'edit'+ inttostr(i+20);
  end;
end;

end.
```